# Seasonal ARIMA with Python, freq H not understood?

Tags: python, statistics, time-series, statsmodels

I am new in here. I am trying to decompose a time serie by following this [TIME SERIE DECOMPOSITION EXAMPLE](http://www.seanabu.com/2016/03/22/time-series-seasonal-ARIMA-model-in-python/) with this [CSV DATA](https://datamarket.com/data/set/22w6/portland-oregon-average-monthly-bus-ridership-100-january-1973-through-june-1982-n114monthly-gambling.12.csv#!ds=22w6&display=line).

My problem is in the *season_decompose* function imported from *statsmodels.tsa.seasonal*.
I am trying to figure out how to apply it to my data without any success.
This is my code :

```
import os
import csv
import time
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm

from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta, date
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import seasonal_decompose

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

from itertools import product

df = pd.read_csv('table.csv', index_col=0)
df.index.name=None
df.reset_index(inplace=True)

start = datetime.strptime("2015-10-10", "%Y-%m-%d")
date_list = [start + relativedelta(days =x , hour=y) for x,y in product(range(0,93), range(0,24))]

df['index'] =date_list
df.set_index(['index'], inplace=True)
df.index.name=None
df.columns= ['Close']
df['Close'] = df.Close.apply(lambda x: int(x))
df.Close.plot(figsize=(12,8), title= 'Monthly Closehip', fontsize=14)


decomposition = seasonal_decompose(df.Close, freq=93)  

fig = decomposition.plot()  
fig.set_size_inches(15, 8)
plt.show()
```

I got the following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 59, in <module>
    decomposition = seasonal_decompose(df.Close, freq=93)  
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/statsmodels/tsa/seasonal.py", line 70, in seasonal_decompose
    pfreq = freq_to_period(pfreq)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/statsmodels/tsa/tsatools.py", line 657, in freq_to_period
    "think this in error.".format(freq))
ValueError: freq H not understood. Please report if you think this in error.
```

The data is a csv file : https://docs.google.com/a/esi.dz/spreadsheets/d/1s2Ak6Rqgm43FV4G_J_giWeHyi38xdZCBCz2v34k7iuA/edit?usp=sharing

Please try and help me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After looking in some blogs, and testing some solutions. I have come with this one :

Adding *values* to df.Close permit to do the decomposition like this :

```
decomposition = seasonal_decompose(df.Close.values, freq=168)
```

Comment: Yes, that's currently necessary. This will be changed soon so that an explicitly specified `freq` is used instead of getting it from the time index of the pandas series in that case.